# Moodle Error: build_navigation() can not be used any more, please use $PAGE->navbar methods instead

Tags: php, moodle

I'm pretty new to Moodle and I tried installing some blocks.
After installing a block, I'm getting this error: `build_navigation() can not be used any more, please use $PAGE->navbar methods instead`.

I think the part of the php file with the error is:

```
$navigation = array(
array('name' => format_string($course->shortname),
'link' => "$CFG->wwwroot/course/view.php?id=$course_id",
'type' => 'course'
),
array('name' => get_string('pluginname', $BLOCK_NAME),
'link' => "$CFG->wwwroot/blocks/user_preferences?id=$course_id",
'type' => 'config'
    ),
);
build_navigation($navigation);
```

I know I'm supposed to use methods as described [here](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Navigation_API), but I don't know how to go about it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`build_navigation` is deprecated since a long time ago. Use this instead:

```
$mycoursestr = format_string($course->shortname);
$mycourseurl = new moodle_url('/course/view.php', ['id' => $courseid])
$PAGE->navbar->add($mycoursestr, $mycourseurl);
```

Notice that `$PAGE` is available in the global scope so you don't need to instantiate it.

Also, depending on what you want to do, for example: depending on where you want this navigation node to appear or wether you are writing this code within an entry point/page (before calling `$OUTPUT->header()`) or elsewhere... you may need to work with the nodes differently.

Comment: It is a nested array that is built into the navigation. How do I do that with the answer you just gave? Can you edit the answer to account for the array. Thanks

Comment: where do you plan to show this links/nodes? breadcrumbs? navigation block? user profile page? Depending on the place you may need to work differently.